# html5 canvas triangle filled color by percentage

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a triangle in canvas and I want to fill it with color .. maybe more than one color .. how I can do that ?

my triangle is here :

```
function draw() {

        var width = 360;  // Triangle Width
        var height = 400; // Triangle Height
        var padding = 90;

        // Draw a path
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(padding + width/2, padding+height);        // Top Corner
        ctx.lineTo(padding + width,  padding); // TOP Right
        ctx.lineTo(padding,  padding);         // TOP Left
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.strokeStyle = "#e8ecef";
        ctx.lineWidth = 25;
        ctx.stroke();



        ctx.restore();
}
```

the current result is like the one in this image : 
[image]

the result I want something like this :

[image]

please any help ? how I can do this ? or if there is any plugin will help me to do this faster ?

Answer (score 4):

### Composition modes

The problem can be solved simply by using a couple of composition modes and very little math (only to calculate correct position).

The receipt would be:

- Draw a mask representing the full triangle background (color does not matter as long as it is opaque)
- Create a gradient with hard transitions to define different color sections.
- Composite a rectangle on top which is clipped to background shape using `source-in` mode.
- Stroke the border using the normal `source-over` mode

All these steps can reuse a single path. The gradient will allow you to define all colored sections in one place. Just make sure each section starts and end with the same color and that the next section will start from where the previous stopped. This will make a hard edge between the sections.

Since the gradient color stops takes normalized values, it becomes a simple task to match any size simply by defining the gradient *line*'s start and stop points relative to the triangle's position and size.

Adjust as needed.

### Example with modified code

I inserted the code in your base code to show where the modifications needs to be.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    width = 360, height = 400, padding = 90, split = 0.33;

// Draw a path that will be reused below
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(padding + width/2, padding+height); // Top Corner
ctx.lineTo(padding + width,  padding);         // TOP Right
ctx.lineTo(padding,  padding);                 // TOP Left
ctx.closePath();

// fill for a mask (color doesn't matter as long as it's opaque)
ctx.fill();

// define gradient
var gr = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, padding, 0, padding+height); // line
gr.addColorStop(0    , "rgb(187, 19, 221)");
gr.addColorStop(split, "rgb(187, 19, 221)");
gr.addColorStop(split, "rgb(38, 199, 222)");
gr.addColorStop(1    , "rgb(38, 199, 222)");

// fill the colored sections (adjust positions as needed)
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
ctx.fillStyle = gr;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

// stroke outline
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#e8ecef";
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=500 height=550></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, a good way to do this is to draw a base triangle and then a trapezium over the top of this, and then do the stroke over these.

```
function draw(percent) {

    var width = 360;  // Triangle Width
    var height = 400; // Triangle Height
    var padding = 90;

    // Draw the purple triangle underneath
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(padding + width/2, padding+height);        // Top Corner
    ctx.lineTo(padding + width,  padding); // TOP Right
    ctx.lineTo(padding,  padding);         // TOP Left

    ctx.fillStyle = "#990099";
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw second triangle/trapezium over the top
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(padding + width*percent/2, padding+height*percent);          //Bottom left
    ctx.lineTo(padding + width - width*percent/2, padding+height*percent);  //Bottom right
    ctx.lineTo(padding + width,  padding); // TOP Right
    ctx.lineTo(padding,  padding);         // TOP Left

    ctx.fillStyle = "#00ccff";
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw the grey line around the triangles
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(padding + width/2, padding+height);        // Top Corner
    ctx.lineTo(padding + width,  padding); // TOP Right
    ctx.lineTo(padding,  padding);         // TOP Left
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#e8ecef";
    ctx.lineWidth = 25;
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.restore();
}

draw(0.1);
```

The draw function works with any value between 0 and 1, where 0 is 0% blue and 1 is 100% blue. As this is a triangle, the area filled will not appear equal if at 50%, however the percentage will be halfway between the top and bottom coordinates.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Triangles and area**

To solve for fraction (p) (0-1) to give new height (h1) for a triangle (w) width and (h) height

Area of triangle is

- w * h * 0.5

Cutting the triangle will give a triangle and a trapezoid.

We will solve so that the fraction area is the area of the trapezoid.

The area of a trapezoid (the other end to the pointy end) in terms of the triangle w,h and h1 where h1 is the unknown height of the trapezoid.

- a1 = w * h1 - (w / 2 * h) * h1 * h1

The h1 * h1 means this solution will be a quadratic so make a formula that equates to 0. We know the area of the trapezoid is the triangle area times the fraction, so use that (w * h * 0.5 * p) and subtract the above area solution in terms of h1 to give

- 0 = w * h * 0.5 * p - w * h1 - (w / 2 * h) * h1<sup>2</sup>

This gives a quadratic the general form is ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c = 0 (in this case the unknown value x is h1 the height of the trapezoid) which can be solved with (-b (+/-) sqrt(b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac) ) / 2a. Because of the (+/-) in the solution there are two answers, at this stage it is unknown which answer is correct.

thus to solve we need a,b,c which are

- a = w/(2*h)
- b = - w
- c = w * h * 0.5 * p

So as a function

```
// return the height of the trapezoid made from a triangle of width height that 
// has an area equal to the area of the triangle * fraction
function getFractionHeightOfTriangle(width,height,fraction){
      var a = width / (2 * height);
      var b = -width;
      var c = width * height * 0.5 * fraction;

      // find the two solutions
      var h1_a = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
      var h1_b = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);

      // from experiment the solution is the second one
      // or you can check which is positive and return that
      return h1_b;  
  }
```

To draw a triangle using the top as the origin

```
// x,y is the top (pointy end) w is width h is height
// col is stroke colour, col1 is fillColour
// lineW is line width.
var drawTriangle = function(x,y,w,h,col,col1,lineW){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.fillStyle = col1;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineW;
    ctx.moveTo(x,y );
    ctx.lineTo(x + w / 2 ,y + h);
    ctx.lineTo(x - w / 2 ,y + h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

To draw part of a triangle

```
// See above function for x,y,w,h,col,col1,lineW
// which is == "top" for pointy end and != "top" for trapezoid
// amount is the height of the top
var drawPartTriangle = function(x,y,w,h,which,amount,col,col1,lineW){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.fillStyle = col1;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineW;
    if(which === "top"){
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w / 2 * (amount / h),y + amount);
        ctx.lineTo(x - w / 2 * (amount / h),y + amount);
    }else{
        ctx.moveTo(x + w / 2 * (amount / h),y + amount);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w / 2 ,y + h);
        ctx.lineTo(x - w / 2 ,y + h);
        ctx.lineTo(x - w / 2 * (amount / h),y + amount);   
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```